# How to run Jupyter notebook on Debian 9 from conda via terminal? (jupyter notebook doesn't work)

Tags: debian, jupyter-notebook

I've installed Anaconda2 and now want to run Jupyter. But when I type

```
jupyther notebook
```

it doesn't work (command not found)

How to run Jupyther?

Comment: Voting to close - This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command is `jupyter` there's no `h`

Comment: @Metropolis - questions that are purely a typo should just be closed with a comment. You're not likely to attract positive attention with this answer.

Comment: I'm following the recommendations from this post: "And little makes me sadder than comments on answers saying, “Don’t answer questions like this – it encourages them.” ... it’s totally cool to answer questions without giving a grilled poop sandwich about exactly what’s allowed. It’s fine to volunteer in one way without being expected to read and enforce every rule and meta discussion since forever." https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/